# No ProjectInfo.xml files were found error from command prompt using MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, loadrunner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm trying out SonarQube using the new MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0.

The Pre-processing works fine

```
E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyKey" /n:"MyProject" /v:"1.0"
.......
Process returned exit code 0
Pre-processing succeeded.
```

Then MSBuild works

```
E:\sonarQube\WebApplication2013>msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.34209
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
........

Done Building Project "E:\sonarQube\WebApplication2013\WebApplication2013.sln" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.51
```

While end command following error gets generated

```
E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
.......
6:35:10 PM  Generating SonarQube project properties file to E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
6:35:10 PM  No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.
6:35:10 PM  Writing processing summary to E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
6:35:10 PM  Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
6:35:10 PM  Creating a summary markdown file...
Process returned exit code 1
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Required your assistance

Comment: Are you running all of the commands from the same directory? When running from the command line, the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner creates a temporary _.sonarqube_ folder under the current directory that contains config data that is used during the MSBuild phase. If you are executing the MSBuild command from a different directory then the integration targets won't be able to find the config data and won't produce any ProjectInfo.xml files.
Similarly, the call to _MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end_  also uses the _.sonarqube_ temp directory so it needs to be run from the same directory too.

Comment: My directory structure is like the E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe which is run through windows command prompt. And my project is in E:\sonarQube\WebApplication2013\WebApplication2013.sln where msbuild runs through Visual Studio command prompt

Comment: I can see you ran the analysis using MSBuild 4.0. Make sure you place the path to MSBuild 12.0 into your PATH environment variable, so MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner will use the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by duncanpMS's comment, you need to run all the 3 commands from the folder of the project you want to analyze.

Here is how:

1. `cd E:\sonarQube\WebApplication2013`
2. `E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyKey" /n:"MyProject" /v:"1.0"`
3. `msbuild /t:rebuild`
4. `E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end`

You can add `E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0` to your `%PATH%` environment variable so that you can simply type `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` instead of the full path from the command line when you analyze projects.

Comment: Thanks it helped me to work.

Then it shown me database connection error.

After updating the database connection string from sql server to my sql, It is showing me **Unable to read the SonarQube analysis settings file 'E:\sonarQube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0\SonarQube.Analysis.xml'. Please fix the content of this file.**

What could be the problem here

Comment: I guess there simply is an issue with the XML formatting, perhaps you missed a closing tag, or added some special characters without escaping them. You can use Visual Studio to edit the XML or another IDE and validate that it is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

You need msbuild version 12 or version 14. If you have VS2013 , Msbuild version 12 comes with it. If you have VS2015, Msbuild version 14 comes with it.

If you don't have , download Microsoft Build Tools 2013 or 2015.

Run `Msbuild -version` to verify the version before running the 3 commands sequentially in the solution folder.